# CMFCToolbar and CMDIFrameWnd

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack, cmfctoolbar

I am converting some CToolbars to CMFCToolbars, my CMainFrame inherits from a CMDIFrameWnd class. However I can find no way to dock a CPane / CMFCToolbar to a CMDIFrameWnd, every tutorial or source I have seen uses a CMDIFrameWndEx as the CMainFrame class.

Can anyone confirm that CPane / CMFCToolbars can only be used on CMDIFrameWndEx frames?
and if the CPane / CMFCToolbars can be used with CMDIFrameWnd then some code samples?

Comment: All of the MFC Feature Pack stuff (which is basically what you're talking about) will require your `CMainFrame` to derive from `CMDIFrameWndEx`, which itself is derived from `CMDIFrameWnd`, so this shouldn't cause you a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching source code for CBasePane, it appears CMDIFrameWnd CANNOT be used for docking/displaying of CMFCToolBar.

In "afxbasepane.cpp" CBasePane::AdjustDockingLayout(...), CMDIFrameWnd is not listed as an acceptable ParentFrame.

There may be some workaround, but I have no evidence of one.